# C ascii character list

Tags: c, list, ascii

This is a  C program that i am trying to make print a list of ASCII characters. I could make the program print a range of numbers, 
bit i cannot get it to print the ASCII value of each number in the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 127

int main(void) 
{   
    int n;  
    int c;

    for (n=32; n<=N; n++) {
        char c = atoi( n); 
        printf("%d", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` converts ASCII to `int`. You are passing it `n`. `n` is not ASCII; it is `int`. Therefore, `atoi(n)` does not work.

After deleting that, what you want to do is print the ASCII character that `n` represents. You do this with:

```
printf("%c", n);
```

You might want to label each character with its number, like this:

```
for (n=32; n<=N; n++) {
    printf("%d: %c\n", n, n);
}
```

Incidentally. this requires that your C implementation use ASCII for its execution character set (and for its “C locale”). Many do. However, this program will not be portable to an implementation that uses a different character set.

Answer (score 1):

Use %c for the ASCII value, like so: `printf("%d, %c\n", n, n);`
Then remove the `atoi()` line.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
printf("%d", c)
```

with

```
printf("%c", c)
```

Also, you don't need atoi.

Just the following is enough:

```
int main(void) 
{   
    int n;  

    for (n=32; n<=N; n++) {
        printf("%c", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using %c as format specifier instead of %d.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 127
int main(void) 
{   
    int n;  
    for (n=32; n<=N; n++)
        printf("%c", n);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`printf` formats](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Indeed, `%d` is used to print signed decimal integers. You want to print the corresponding character, so the format you are looking for is `%c`.

So it gives :

```
printf("%d", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (n=32; n<=N; n++) {
    printf("%c", n);
}
```

You can print `n` to characters directly using `%c`

Note that you defined two variable `c`, the inner one (`char c`)will shadow the outer one(`int c`), that's valid C, but usually bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Atoi convert ascii entry in int representation. 
The program is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 127

int main()
{
  int n;

  for (n=32; n<=N; n++) 
    printf("%c",n) ;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Final solution

---

### I tried to make it so compact (although not obfuscated) as possible.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  // for loop                                      //  outputs                |data type|
  // for(int i='a';i<='z';putchar(i),i++);          // a,b,c...x,y,z          |  char   |
  // for(int i='a';i<='z';printf("%c\n",i),i++);    // a,b,c...x,y,z          |  char   |
  // for(int i='A';i<='Z';putchar(i),i++);          // A,B,C...X,Y,Z          |  char   |
  for(int i='a';i<='z';printf("%d\n",i),i++);     // 97,98,99..120,121,122    |  ascii  |
  //for(int i='a';i<='z';printf("%x\n",i),i++);       // 61,62,63 ,78,79,7a   |  hex    |

 //// for(int i='a';i<'z';printf("%d\n",i),F(i < 5),i++);
// for(int i='a';i<='z'; printf("%c\n",i),i++);
  return 0;
}
```